# How can i stream to all clients?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I am trying to broadcast a server event with Snap based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/deckool/faefa70142e4b2b915d8).
The problem is that when another client connects the messages are splitted between them so client 1 gets event 1, client 2 gets event 2 and don't seems to get the hint why.

I am trying to all the clients to get also event 1 and 2.

Thanks