# Write EventSource Handlers in the Snap Framwork

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I have web based chat app written in Haskell's Snap Web framework, it currently uses web sockets. For a variety of reasons I want to move from Websockets to Server Sent Events. Some of my reasons are: Web sockets not being included in HTTP 2.0, and EventSource is more suited to interface with a functional language.

I'm looking for any tips, documentation, advice, right-direction-pointing ect..
related to the Snap framework and Sever Sent Events / EventSource

Comment: i also have something like this, with reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547361/how-can-i-stream-to-all-clients) but with no response. You can find a part of the code [in here](https://gist.github.com/deckool/faefa70142e4b2b915d8) but without streaming to all clients.